# Jupyter Notebook cannot open and have error expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

[Error Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch9ZI.png)
[Anaconda Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roIOP.png)

I want to install tensorflow on my jupyter notebook. I followed the steps on Google but was told to create a virtual environment. Until the steps are finished. When I open a jupyter notebook that uses a virtual environment it can, while the jupyter notebook that I normally use (Root base) doesn't it can be opened with an error like the picture above. Finally I tried to delete the virtual environment, but it still can't be opened

I want to install tensorflow on my jupyter notebook. I followed the steps on Google but was told to create a virtual environment. Until the steps are finished. When I open a jupyter notebook that uses a virtual environment it can, while the jupyter notebook that I normally use (Root base) doesn't it can be opened with an error like the picture above. Finally I tried to delete the virtual environment, but it still can't be opened

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.